# In Spring Batch ThreadPoolTaskExecutor references are not garbage collected

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor

I am working on Spring Batch and using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to fork multiple threads.
The files are huge like 175 MB and I am dealing with lots of Strings objects.
Due to this OutOfMemory error is getting thrown.

Below config will invoke 1 thread to process 1 file(customDBPartitioner is picking up the files).

Here is the config :

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
</bean>

<step id="unixPartitionerStep">
        <partition step="unixItemStep" partitioner="customDBPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="threadPoolTaskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </step>
<listeners>
        <listener ref="unixJobListener" />
    </listeners>
```

So when this step is invoked : 3 threads starts processing files, to keep a check on memory I have put a condition in stepListener.

`while(preProcessorUtil.getAvailableMemory() < minimumMemoryRequired) {
                logger.info("Thread going to sleep as memory is not enough - " +  inputFile.getFilename());
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }`

What I am trying is If enough memory is not available then dont go to execute the step for processing next file.

After available memory falls below the memoryRequired, the thread goes to sleep mode but GC never gets called and instead memory keeps on decreasing.

Can someone please help and let me know what is the issue here, how to reclaim the memory to process the files?

**EDIT :**
In JvisualVM, most memory is taken by Strings/chars

Chunk Size is 1
That is : I am asking each thread to read/work on one file at a time. File size varies from KBs to 100's MB.
I can't choose an option to process file line by line because while processing
I have to refer different sections in the file.
Here is the code from the Reader, It is reading one file in one chunk

```
StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder()
        try {
         // I tried this as well.
        //file.append(FileUtils.readFileToString(resource.getFile()));
        logger.info("Size of file : "+ resource.getFilename() +" is " + FileUtils.sizeOf(resource.getFile())/1024 + " KB");
        synchronized(UnixFileItemReader.class) {
            lineIterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(resource.getFile());
            /*while(PreProcessorUtil.getAvailableMemoryNoLogs() < minimumMemoryRequired) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }*/
            while (lineIterator.hasNext()) {
                file.append(lineIterator.nextLine()).append("\r\n");
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        file = null;
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        LineIterator.closeQuietly(lineIterator);
    }
```

After reading the whole file in a StringBuilder, I do lot of pattern matching in the  Processor.

Comment: How big is your chunk size?  Also, multithreaded reading of a file typically doesn't gain much of a benefit via performance.

Comment: Your memory leak is not in the code you posted. You should post your actual I/O code or code that uses hash maps. My first guess is you're not closing the streams that are reading files into memory.

Comment: I just edited my question to cover up above questions.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, you may have to analyze the jmap dunp files with Eclipse MAT or some other tools at the end. As the problem can have relation with every detail of your code.

I just give a possible reason here:  ExecutorService has a BlockingQueue used for waiting jobs, these waiting jobs also keep memory. So if submitting the job too fast, it's easy to get a out-of-memory.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be the case, I have tried sleep method as well to slow down the execution.